# Incompatible pointer assignment error in C when implementing a stack with structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, compiler-errors, stack

I hope the details below help, but to summarize... I am trying to implement a stack data structure using structs. I receive only one error about incompatible pointer types when assigning however they are both single pointers to my struct. However, I do have an issue which I can't understand, the pointer type I am trying to assign (show below) has a type of `'StackNode * (*)(int)'`, which I cannot seem to understand why, it should just be `StackNode *`.

Does anyone have an answer? Thank you.

My error given is this...

```
    Problem1.c:63:14: warning: assignment to ‘StackNode *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘StackNode * (*)(int)’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
       63 |         root = newNode;//inserting at the front of the stack, so make sure to set our root node to point to newNode
```

My code block which I am having trouble with is this function:

```
    //This is a function that will create a new StackNode structure given some data and return pointer to the node
    StackNode* newNode(int data){
        StackNode* newNode = (StackNode*)malloc(sizeof(StackNode)); //allocate memory for the newly made stacknode
        newNode->data = data; //set the data
        newNode->next = NULL; //set the next node to null
        return newNode;
    }
```

The full code which I have written is as follows:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <limits.h>

    //type definition for each node in the queue
    typedef struct StackNode{
        int data;
        struct StackNode* next;
    }StackNode;

    //function prototype definitions
    int isEmpty(StackNode*);
    int peek(StackNode*);
    int pop(StackNode*);
    void push(StackNode*, int);
    StackNode* newNode(int data);

    int main(){
        
        int userInput = 0;
        int validInput = 1;
        
        StackNode *root = NULL;
        
        while(validInput){
            printf("Please enter a value to push into the stack");
            scanf("%d", &userInput);
            
            if(userInput>=0){
                push(root, userInput);
                printf("%d pushed to stack\n", userInput);//print the data we to the stack
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
        
        while(root!=NULL){
            printf("%d was popped from the stack\n", root->data);
        }
        
        return 0;
    }

    int isEmpty(StackNode* root){
        return !root; //NULL evaluates to false, so this returns whether it isnt null or not
    }


    //pushes a new node to the top of the stack by taking in data and using our function newNode to make a new node from the data.
    //takes in a pointer to the root node since we want to adjust the stack.
    void push(StackNode* root, int data){
        StackNode* node = newNode(data); //create a new node from our data.
        node->next = root;//insert at the front of the stack, so save the node root is pointing at and make newNode point there
        root = newNode;//inserting at the front of the stack, so make sure to set our root node to point to newNode
    }

    //removes the first node and returns the value stored by it, makes sure to free the root node. 
    //It takes in a pointer to the root node since we want to free the space taken by the root node.
    int pop(StackNode *root){
        if(isEmpty(root)){
            return INT_MIN; //return smallest possible integer since root doesnt exist
        }
        
        StackNode* temp = root; //sets a temporary node equal to the root node in order to free it after we are done
        int poppedData = temp->data;//get the data from the root node 
        
        root = root->next;//set the root node to the next node in line
        free(temp); //since we we no longer want the root node in memory, free it by freeing our temp node.
        
        return poppedData; //return the data the root is storing.
    }

    //show the data stored at the top of the stack without removing the node itself, takes in pointer to root node
    int peek(StackNode *root){ 
        if(isEmpty(root)){
            return INT_MIN; //return smallest possible integer since root doesnt exist
        }
        
        return root->data; //return the data the root is storing.
    }

    //This is a function that will create a new StackNode structure given some data and return pointer to the node
    StackNode* newNode(int data){
        StackNode* newNode = (StackNode*)malloc(sizeof(StackNode)); //allocate memory for the newly made stacknode
        newNode->data = data; //set the data
        newNode->next = NULL; //set the next node to null
        return newNode;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `push`

```c
root = newNode;
```

`newNode` is a function!
you probably meant

```c
root=node;
```

Comment: Haha you are exactly right! I cannot believe I overlooked this. Thank you!